# How can have reflect.field library the value of a Field?

Tags: java, xml, javafx

I am doing an application, and I need to create 10 TextFields and save value in a XML file that i have. (I know how to save it in XML)

The issue I have is I want to save it all (in a XML) automatically without repeating the code like 10 times for each variable.

I am trying reflect.Field library to do it (Not accomplished) but i don't know if it's the best solution.

```
    public TextField Tf_TestI1;
    public TextField Tf_TestF1;
    public TextField Tf_TestI2;
    public TextField Tf_TestF2;
    public TextField Tf_TestI3;
    public TextField Tf_TestF3;
    public TextField Tf_TestI4;
    public TextField Tf_TestF4;
    public TextField Tf_TestI5;
    public TextField Tf_TestF5;
//Pair them and save it in XML
private void stuffVariables(){
        String nameField1=  "Tf_TestI";
        String nameField2=  "Tf_TestF";
        Field[] fields = Controller.class.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i <fields.length ; i++) {
            if (fields[i].getName().startsWith(nameField1)){
                for (int j = 0; j < fields.length ; j++) {
                    if (fields[j].getName().equals(nameField2+fields[i].getName().substring(fields[i].getName().length()-1))){
                        System.out.println("EQUALS : "+fields[i].getName() + " = "+ fields[j].getName());
                        try {
                            //System.out.println("1: "+fields[i].getValue);

                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am trying to get the pair of Test Initial and Final to finally save it in XML like this...

```
    <TESTS>
          <TEST>
            <INITIAL>AD</INITIAL>
            <FINAL>AVB</FINAL>
          </TEST>
          <TEST>
            <INITIAL>AQEW</INITIAL>
            <FINAL>AVFE</FINAL>
          </TEST>
    <!--   ... MORE TEST -->
    <TESTS>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra I will have it in mind. PD: It's an example code.

Comment: Reflection is almost never the best way to accomplish something.  If you want to store repeated data, you probably want an array or [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

Comment: I am curious about what `Controller.class.getFields()` does?

Comment: any code you are showing to others - particularly those you expect help from - should be as readable as possible, following conventions is part of a successful communication ;)

Comment: @Sedrick it returns you all the "Fields", all the public variables in that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main objective was to make it easy when I add more TextFields...
Using HashMap I only have to add a Key to his Value.
Using numbers in the Key made it more easy in my case.

```
 //[...]
 Map<String, TextField> map; //Global variable
 //I just have to add the new TextFields to the HashMap
 private void mapSaveRangs() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("rangInitial1", tfrangInitial1);
    map.put("rangFinal1", tfrangFinal1);
    map.put("rangInitial2", tfrangInitial2);
    map.put("rangFinal2", tfrangFinal2);
    map.put("rangInitial3", tfrangInitial3);
    map.put("rangFinal3", tfrangFinal3);
    map.put("rangInitial4", tfrangInitial4);
    map.put("rangFinal4", tfrangFinal4);
    map.put("rangInitial5", tfrangInitial5);
    map.put("rangFinal5", tfrangFinal5);
}

private void rangsInPairsXML(Element peeRangs) {
    String sKeyrInitial = "rangInitial";
    String sValuerInitial;
    String sKeyrFinal = "rangFinal";
    String sValuerFinal;
    //Making sure that we have pair of 2 
    if (map.size() % 2 == 0) {
        //map half size loop
        for (int numRang = 1; numRang <= map.size() / 2; numRang++) {
            sValuerInitial = map.get(sKeyrInitial + numRang).getText();
            sValuerFinal = map.get(sKeyrFinal + numRang).getText();

            //Verifying values and saving it in peeRang (XML Element)
            if (!(sValuerInitial.equals("") || sValuerFinal.equals(""))) {
                Element eRang = new Element("RANG");
                eRang.addContent(new Element("INITIAL").addContent(sValuerInitial));
                eRang.addContent(new Element("FINAL").addContent(sValuerFinal));
                peeRangs.addContent(eRang);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR!!");
        //[...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* the way you want to do it. As a general rule of thumb, if you feel the need to use reflection, you're doing it wrong.

It looks like you have an arbitrary number of pairs of `TextField` objects. So that's the first port of call - create a separate class to house those pairs of `TextField`:

```
class TextFieldPair {

    private TextField initialVal;
    private TextField finalVal;

    public TextFieldPair(TextField initialVal, TextField finalVal) {
        this.initialVal = initialVal;
        this.finalVal = finalVal;
    }

    public TextField getInitialVal() {
        return initialVal;
    }

    public TextField getFinalVal() {
        return finalVal;
    }

}
```

...you then want an arbitrary number of these objects. Every time you have an arbitrary number of objects you'll want to use a collection of some sort, such as a list, so we can then loop through them like so:

```
public class Main {

    private List<TextFieldPair> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //...Other code that adds textfield objects to the above list

    private void stuffVariables() {
        for(TextFieldPair pair : list) {
            System.out.println("Initial value: " + pair.getInitialVal().getText());
            System.out.println("Initial value: " + pair.getFinalVal().getText());
        }
    }

}
```

You'll then have all the values printed out from each of those `TextField` objects, and you can manipulate them (such as outputting XML instead) as you see fit.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I want to make it more "automatic" today I only have pair of 5 (I am adding it 1by1), imagine if I need more 20 pairs more, the objective is to make the function automatic, that gets all the fields of the Controller class and selects what I need (some if and elses) and finally adds it in the XML File. If I need more pairs I only want to initialize it in the Controller. Is this possible to do?